# Convert PS file to PDF in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I need to convert (input) PS file to (output) PDF file via Visual C++. And after converting i need to display the pdf file in a window.

Could any one help me in this ?. How can i proceed further ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `system ("ps2pdf.exe in.ps out.pdf");` using ps2pdf utility from Ghostscript.

Answer (score 0):

To display the pdf you could use [Poppler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software)). For the conversion, I second the use of [ps2pdf](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/svn/Ps2pdf.htm)

Answer (score 0):

i use PStill - http://www.pstill.com/  it was about 60 dollars.  been used in a production environment for over 2 years, converting 200-500 files a day.